# JSON information is looped once

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So the problem is that I'm loading JSON files from url into my html and it's working perfectly besides for the fact that it shows the information twice..
Does anyone know why this is the case?

Here's the Jquery/Javascript code that I use to load the JSON into my html.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://datatank4.gent.be//bevolking/totaalaantalinwoners.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        i = 0;
        var access;
        var url;
        $(data).each(function(index, value) {
            wijkname = value.wijk;
            year = value.year_2010;
            i++;
            $('#pagewrap2').append(
                '<div class="dataond col col-xxs-12 col-md-3"> <h2> ' + wijkname + '</h2><p>' + year + '<div id="maps">' + "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'  marginheight='0' marginwidth='0'   src='https://maps.google.com/maps?&amp;q="+ encodeURIComponent( wijkname + ' ' + 'Gent' ) +"&amp;output=embed'></iframe>" + '</div>' + '</p></div>'
            );
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm showing it working properly. http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/wocL2r9t/

Comment: Yea I can see that and that's very strange. Maybe it has something to do with my html then?

Answer (score 1):

First check the response of this ajax call.

If the response look fine maybe you're making the ajax call twice.

For example when you add an event listener twice. (add [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function before click() if you're using jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. Really stupid but I linked my file twice in my index.html...
Thanks everyone for your replies.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var categoriesId = [];
      $.getJSON("http://datatank4.gent.be//bevolking/totaalaantalinwoners.json", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, item) {

          categoriesId.push(item.wijk);


        }
              );
        for (i = 0; i < categoriesId.length; i++) {

            alert(categoriesId[i]);

 var newInProductPriceDiv = document.createElement('div');
              newInProductPriceDiv.setAttribute('id', "recentlyViewedProductPriceDiv" + i);
              newInProductPriceDiv.setAttribute('class', "subcategoryListPriceDiv");
              newInProductPriceDiv.innerHTML = newInProductPriceDiv.innerHTML + categoriesId[i];
              document.getElementById('pagewrap2' + i).appendChild(newInProductPriceDiv);
        }
      }
               );

    }
                     );
  </script>
```

if you have any confusion then tell me ok . and if you not get your exactly output then also tell me.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. I'm not very good with code so please explain it to me like you would to a 5-year old.